# Why does IRB not ignore EOF as per IRB.conf hash

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm trying to start IRB and run a file, foo.rb, in one command,

```
irb foo.rb
```

When foo.rb is done I want another IRB prompt. Instead, it prints an IRB prompt, then exits.

I checked the IRB docs and I changed `IRB.conf[:IGNORE_EOF] = true`. I confirmed that hash value inside IRB. Is the behavior I want set by this hash? If so, what else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for `irb` say about that configuration:

```
**conf.ignore_eof = true/false**
   Whether ^D (control-d) will be ignored or not.  If false is set, ^D means quit.
```

So, no that setting isn't meant to do what you're looking for. As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to do what you want with `irb`. The closest would be to start `irb` without an argument, then use `require './foo.rb'` to run that file.